# Browser crash when using marker cluster in leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson, clustering

When using the following portion of code, the clusters and some markers are shown but if I zoom or click anywhere the browser crashes.

```
var cam = L.ExtraMarkers.icon({
             icon: 'fa-video-camera',
             markerColor: 'red',
             shape: 'square',
             prefix: 'fa'
          });

var cameras = omnivore.kml('json/cameras.kml')
            .on('ready', function(layer) {
               this.eachLayer(function(marker) {
                 marker.setIcon(cam);
                 var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();
                 var popupCam = marker.toGeoJSON().properties.name;
                 marker.bindPopup(popupCam);
                 markers.addLayer(cameras);
                 map.addLayer(markers);
               })
             });
```

Without using the clustering, all markers (~300) are shown pretty well so I guess it should not be performance related.

Comment: Which browser? Which version of Leaflet? Can you publish a demo which can crash *my* browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So for each of your 300 markers, you create a Cluster Group, to which you add the entire `cameras` GeoJSON group (300 markers), and add the former Cluster Group to the map?

300 cluster groups with 300 markers each?

There is a high chance this is what slows down your browser, possibly making it crash.

I guess you wanted to put your code with Cluster Group *outside* your `eachLayer` loop.

```js
var cameras = omnivore.kml('json/cameras.kml')
  .on('ready', function(layer) {
    this.eachLayer(function(marker) {
      marker.setIcon(cam);
      var popupCam = marker.toGeoJSON().properties.name;
      // Could probably have used popupCam = marker.feature.properties.name?
      marker.bindPopup(popupCam);
    })
    var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();
    markers.addLayer(cameras);
    map.addLayer(markers);
  });
```